# A problem regarding probability exercises.

Tags: probability

I have run into a thinking error while trying to solve the following two exercises, here they are:

1) There are 30 fish in the lake. 5 of them have been taken out and marked and then put back into the lake. Later 7 fish have been picked from the lake. What is the probability that 2 out of 7 picked fish were marked?

2) A group of tourists which consists of 15 boys and 5 girls are to participate in a tournament. They need to pick 4 people out of all. What is the probability that their team will consist out of 2 boys and 2 girls?

I have no problems regarding combinatoric calculations, however, there is a logical conundrum that I fail to overcome.

1) In my math book, it is explained that in the first problem you have to find the total number of possible outcomes using formula A(30,7)= 30!/7! which then says that the order in which we take out our fish is important (A, B, C) and (C, B, A) group of fishes should be regarded as different and calculated as three separate variants. The same goes for the number of favorable outcomes which is found with formula A(5,2)*C(25,5)=(5!/3!)* (25/20!). The results of our probability is 253/20358.

2) In this exercise, it is explained that when trying to find the number of all the possible outcomes we use formula C(20,4)=20!/(4!*16!) and the number of favorable outcomes if C(15,2)*C(5,2)=(15!/(2!*13!)) * (5!/(2!*3!)). When you divide two the answers is 70/323.

My question is: What makes these two problems so different, that in the first one you have to count all the possible outcomes concerning the order of a group of elements (which means that group (A, B) *A is fish number 1 and B is fish number 2* and (B, A) are two different possible outcomes) and in the second exercise there is no difference between a group (A, B) and (B, A) *A is boy number 1 and B is boy number 2* and they are counted as the same outcome?

Comment: Uh, I don't think you need to care about the order for the first one either (you can do it while fixing orders of course); should the first one not just be $\frac{\binom{25}{5} \binom{5}{2}}{\binom{30}{7}}$?

Comment: And then your probability according to my calculations will be 0.260 which just does not make any sense

Comment: Why does it not? It is a number between 0 and 1, and is not unreasonably small or large (it is a bit big I guess, but you would expect around 5/30 * 7 many unmarked samples (which is 1.something); so the probability being around 0.26 seems much likelier than say 1 in a 100).

Comment: Get your point. When I was making your calculation I came to the conclusion that the probability of 0.26 is unreasonably big. We pick 7 fish out of 30 with 5 being marked and we expect that 1 / 4 times there will be exactly 2 ( no more no less) marked fish among 7. The probability of 0.26 is just far too big. In my opinion 1/100 is way more likely. Thank you for helping me out  :) .

Comment: There are just $6$ possibilities for the number of marked fish in the sample.  While $1$ is the most likely number, $2$ is not that much different than $1$.  So I don't know why you'd think $1/100$ is a reasonable probability.  If $0$, $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$ all had probabilities $\le 1/100$, the probability of $1$ would have to be $\ge 95/100$.

Comment: Assuming the fish are _not_ put back in the lake the second time around, @E-A is correct. Another way to think about why 0.26 _is_ reasonable is this: Very, very roughly, every time a fish is picked there is a 1/6 chance that it will be tagged - on the first pick 1/6, the second pick 1/6, the third pick 1/6 etc. So, in seven picks we are asking what is the likelihood that _any_ two of those will be tagged? Order does _not_ matter. (Of course, strictly the probabilities are changing with each pick, but they will be increasing the chance of picking a tagged fish.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is *there is no reason* why you have to compute one probability according to the order of the objects for one problem and without regard to order for the other. You can do it either way for either problem if you count the orderings correctly.

---

Here are some ways you can compute probabilities for the fish.
Let $X$ be the random variable equal to the number of marked fish among the seven fish later taken from the pond.
The question asks for the probability $P(X = 2),$ but we can just as well compute the probability for any number of marked fish from $0$ to $5.$ (There cannot be more than $5$ marked fish among the seven fish because there are only $5$ marked fish in the lake.)

For any number $m$ of marked fish among the seven fish taken later, 
there are $u = 7 - m$ unmarked fish.
Let's try to compute $P(X=m)$ using the method described in the question.
Then we have $A(30,7) = 30!/23! = 10260432000$ possible ways to take the seven fish from the lake (where we count the order in which the fish were taken),
$A(5,m)$ ways to take the marked fish, and $A(25,u)$ ways to take the unmarked fish,
for a total of $N = A(5,m)A(25,u)$ ways (according to this method).
Dividing $N$ by $A(30,7)$ we get the following probabilities for each $m$:

\begin{array}{ccrrrl}
m & u & C(25,u)\quad & C(5,m) & N\qquad & \ P(X=m) \\
0 & 7 & 2422728000 &   1\quad & 2422728000 & 0.236123391 \\
1 & 6 &  127512000 &   5\quad &  637560000 & 0.062137735 \\
2 & 5 &    6375600 &  20\quad &  127512000 & 0.012427547 \\
3 & 4 &     303600 &  60\quad &   18216000 & 0.001775364 \\
4 & 3 &      13800 & 120\quad &    1656000 & 0.000161397 \\
5 & 2 &        600 & 120\quad &      72000 & 0.000007017 \\
  &   &            &          &            & 0.312632451
\end{array}

The probability $P(X=2)$ matches the probability
$253/20358$ computed in the question.

But recall that by the law of total probability, if we have a disjoint list of all possible outcomes (as we do here), the sum of their probabilities should be $1.$
But it is less than $0.313.$ So there is clearly something wrong in the calculations.

Let's try it again without distinguishing the order in which the fish are taken from the lake. We then have $C(30,7) = 2035800$ possible ways to take the seven fish.
We also have $C(5,m)$ ways to take the marked fish, and $C(25,u)$ ways to take the unmarked fish,
for a total of $N = C(5,m)C(25,u)$ ways to take $m$ marked fish and $u$ unmarked fish. The probabilities work out as follows:

\begin{array}{ccrrrl}
m & u & C(25,u) & C(5,m) & N\quad & \ P(X=m) \\
0 & 7 & 480700\ &  1\quad & 480700 & 0.236123391  \\
1 & 6 & 177100\ &  5\quad & 885500 & 0.434964142  \\
2 & 5 &  53130\ & 10\quad & 531300 & 0.260978485  \\
3 & 4 &  12650\ & 10\quad & 126500 & 0.062137735  \\
4 & 3 &   2300\ &  5\quad &  11500 & 0.005648885  \\
5 & 2 &    300\ &  1\quad &    300 & 0.000147362  \\
  &   &        &    &        & 1
\end{array}

We see that now the most likely outcome is $X=1,$ and the probabilities sum to $1.$

So what is the mistake in the first set of calculations?

In the first set of calculations, we counted taking marked fish $(m_1,m_2)$ and $(m_2,m_1)$ as separate outcomes,
and we also counted unmarked fish $(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5)$ and
$(u_2,u_1,u_3,u_4,u_5)$ as separate outcomes when computing the numerator of the probability.
But we did not count $(m_1,m_2,u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5)$ and
$(m_1,u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5,m_2)$ as separate outcomes in the numerator,
whereas we *did* count them as separate outcomes in the denominator.
So we did not count the numerator and denominator in the same way.

To correct this, in the numerator we should account not only for the different sequences in which the  marked fish might be taken,
and the different sequences in which the unmarked fish might be taken,
but we must also count the different ways in which the marked and unmarked fish might be interleaved in the sequence of seven fish.
This is $(7,m)$, the number of ways the $m$ marked fish might take their places in the sequence of seven fish. (Or you could equally well say it is $(7,u)$; it is the same number.) So the numerator should be
$N = A(5,m)A(25,u)C(7,m).$
If we do the computation that way we get these results:

\begin{array}{ccrrrrl}
m & u & A(25,u)\quad & A(5,m) & C(7,m) & N\qquad & \ P(X=m) \\
0 & 7 & 2422728000 &   1\ &  1\quad & 2422728000 & 0.236123391 \\
1 & 6 &  127512000 &   5\ &  7\quad & 4462920000 & 0.434964142 \\
2 & 5 &    6375600 &  20\ & 21\quad & 2677752000 & 0.260978485 \\
3 & 4 &     303600 &  60\ & 35\quad &  637560000 & 0.062137735 \\
4 & 3 &      13800 & 120\ & 35\quad &   57960000 & 0.005648885 \\
5 & 2 &        600 & 120\ & 21\quad &    1512000 & 0.000147362 \\
  &   &        &    &        &  & 1
\end{array}

Now the results agree with the second set of calculations.

In general, when you want the probability of some event when drawing objects with replacement, if you can compute the probability by considering the objects drawn without regard to the order in which they are drawn, you can also compute the probability *with* regard to the order in which the objects are drawn.
You merely must count all orderings correctly.
This makes sense because the marked fish should not suddenly become more or less likely to be caught in the net just because we start (or stop) paying attention to the order in which the fish are caught.

Comment: Thank you very much! I completely forgot to make calculations when counting the possible variants of C(7,m). Now it all makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When doing probability, the important thing is to consider order (or not) in both numerator (favorable outcomes) and denominator (total outcomes).

Regarding the first problem. If order is important, then total outcomes are 
$$A_7^{30}=\frac{30!}{23!}$$
and favorable outcomes are
$${7\choose2}A_2^5A_5^{25}=\frac{7!}{2!5!}\frac{5!}{3!}\frac{25!}{20!}$$
The ${7\choose2}$ decide where the marked fish are taken. The probability is $0.2609\ldots$

If order is not important, then total outcomes are 
$${30\choose7}=\frac{30!}{7!23!}$$
and favorable outcomes are
$${5\choose2}{25\choose5}=\frac{5!}{2!3!}\frac{25!}{5!20!}$$
The probability is, again, $0.2609\ldots$

This probability may seem high, but it was expected. This is used in biology to evalutate a fish population in an area. The idea is that the ratio of marked/unmarked fish taken the second time should be the same as the ratio of taken/population the first time. With this example, $5$ marked fish in a population on $30$, should give
$$\frac M7=\frac5{30}\implies M=1.166\ldots$$
With $7$ fish the second time, we expect to have a bit more than $1$ marked. So $2$ is highly probable.

Comment: Thank you! :)))