# From 5 red and 4 black balls, what's the probability that a red and a black ball is chosen?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, conditional-probability

An urn contains 5 red balls and 4 black balls. A sample of two balls is selected at random. What is the probability that the sample contains one red and one white ball?

The answer as I have it is: $\frac{{5\choose 1} \times {4\choose 1}}{9 \choose 2} = \frac{5}{9}$

On the other hand, If I use the formula: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) . P(B|A)$ gives $\frac{5}{9}.\frac{4}{8} = \frac{5}{18}$. Not the Answer!!

Here, Am I taking the question in a wrong way? When I do $\frac{5}{9}.\frac{4}{8} = \frac{5}{18}$, is it that it only calculates the part where the first ball is Red and the second is Black and leaves out the part that the first ball is Black and the second ball is Red? If so, then I do get the right answer $\frac{5}{9}.\frac{4}{8} + \frac{4}{9}.\frac{5}{8} = 2 \times \frac{5}{9}.\frac{4}{8} = \frac{5}{9}$

Which means the right question I should ask is "What is the probability that the two balls are different colors?"

Somehow using combinatorial formula captures the whole thing in a single step that I don't need to worry about each case separately, although on the numerator we considered the red ball first, then the black ball. As it is a combination and the order does not matter it seems that the numerator should be divided by 2:  $\displaystyle{\frac{\frac{5 \times 4}{2}}{9 \choose 2}}$ Which is very confusing.

My question is the whole thing seems a little confusing to me. Can anyone please address:

- if I'm right about using the $P(A\cap B) formula$
- What exactly is wrong about the $\displaystyle{\frac{\frac{5 \times 4}{2}}{9 \choose 2}}$ part?
- Can you please explain the whole thing probably with an example in a generic that also works for other similar questions.

Comment: "An urn contains 5 red balls and 4 black balls. A sample of two balls is selected at random. What is the probability that the sample contains one red and one white ball?" -- Would it not be zero, since there aren't any white balls you can obtain in the first place? All you have is red and black.

Comment: sorry, typo!! thanks for pointing out

Comment: You should edit the question body as well.

Comment: any idea, please? or perhaps you can also edit it I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put numbers on the balls so we can tell exactly which ones are chosen.
So the balls are $(r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5)$ and $(b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4).$

Then all $\binom 92 = 36$ possible pairs of balls that can be selected are listed in the following table:

\begin{array}{ccccc}
\{b_1,r_1\} & \{b_1,r_2\} & \{b_1,r_3\} & \{b_1,r_4\} & \{b_1,r_5\} \\
\{b_2,r_1\} & \{b_2,r_2\} & \{b_2,r_3\} & \{b_2,r_4\} & \{b_2,r_5\} \\
\{b_3,r_1\} & \{b_3,r_2\} & \{b_3,r_3\} & \{b_3,r_4\} & \{b_3,r_5\} \\
\{b_4,r_1\} & \{b_4,r_2\} & \{b_4,r_3\} & \{b_4,r_4\} & \{b_4,r_5\} \\
\{r_1,r_2\} & \{r_1,r_3\} & \{r_1,r_4\} & \{r_1,r_5\} & \{r_2,r_3\} \\
\{r_2,r_4\} & \{r_2,r_5\} & \{r_3,r_4\} & \{r_3,r_5\} & \{r_4,r_5\} \\
\{b_1,b_2\} & \{b_1,b_3\} & \{b_1,b_4\} & \{b_2,b_3\} & \{b_2,b_4\} \\
\{b_3,b_4\}.
\end{array}

The first four rows of five pairs (containing $4 \times 5$ pairs!), 
you may observe, includes every pair that has one red ball and one black ball.
The remaining $16$ pairs are either both red or both black.

If you pay attention to which ball is drawn first, of course, you get
ordered pairs instead of the unordered sets listed above,
and for each sequence of balls in the table above there is another
opposite sequence; for example both $(b_1,r_1)$ and $(r_1,b_1).$
And you can very well solve the problem by counting those two
sequences separately; but if you count both
$(b_1,r_1)$ and $(r_1,b_1)$ you must also 
count both $(r_1,r_2)$ and $(r_2,r_1),$ 
you must count both $(b_1,b_2)$ and $(b_2,b_1),$ 
and so forth.
Instead of $36$ pairs in the denominator you will have 
$72$ pairs, and the probability $N/D$ will come out the same:

$$ \frac{\binom41 \binom51}{\binom92} = \frac{4\times5}{36} = \frac{5}{9}; $$

$$ \frac{\binom41 \binom51 + \binom51 \binom41}{2\binom92} 
= \frac{4\times5 + 5\times4}{2\times36} = \frac{40}{72} = \frac{5}{9}. $$

Comment: so this is same as using permutation, $\displaystyle{\frac{4 \times 5 + 5 \times 4}{{{}^{9}\!P_{2}}}= \displaystyle{\frac{4 \times 5 + 5 \times 4}{9 \times 8}}=\frac{4 \times 5}{\frac{9\times 8}{2}} = \frac{5}{9}}$, so is it gonna work always i.e. usually in probability, we use combination most of the time like this one- does this mean we can use permutation too?

Comment: Different balls don't suddenly jump into (or out of) your hands just because you start paying attention to which one came out of the urn first. So yes, if you can solve it without respect to order (combinations) you can solve it with respect to order (permutations). But notice that we did not just change each combination to a permutation when accounting for order. Another example of this is https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3593898

Comment: Here, in this case, we can do both ignore the order(combination), not ignore the order(permutation)--but what about using the formula $P(A\cap B)=P(A).P(B|A)$, we need to consider the order, and how can we make a relationship between these two different ways or what should be the intuition behind doing it using the formula?

Comment: There's no order implied by the equation $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B\mid A).$ The order was introduced by your implied definitions of $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is evidently "I draw a red ball first" and $B$ is "I draw a black ball second". If you add the case $P(C\cap D)$ where $C$ is "draw a black ball first" and $D$ is "draw a red ball second" then that would cover it.

Comment: I think the reason that combinations are preferred over permutations in many solutions is that fully accounting for the effects of order/sequence often makes things more complicated.

Comment: what if the question is I draw two balls, what is the probability that they are of different colors? how do we solve in this case using the equation $P(A\cap B) = P(A).P(|A)$? No order is implied here, as neither does the eqn, so just using the eqn should solve it?

Comment: What is $A$? What is $B$? As I said, the equation itself does not impose a dependence on order, but in order to avoid an order dependence you must define both $A$ and $B$ in ways that are independent of order, for example, "at least one ball is red." Then I think you will find that the right side of the equation is actually rather difficult to work out, especially the conditional probability; I guess the easiest way to compute $P(B\mid A)$ in a way independent of order is to solve the original problem some other way and then use the known value of $P(A\cap B)$ to help find $P(B\mid A)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer's been really insightful and cleared a lot of concepts,
one little question by reading the other post you suggested, what if the question is 2 red ball and one black ball(total three now)? how to solve it using permutation or the eqn $P(A\cap B) = P(A).P(|A)$? Add the numerator 6 times/multiply by 6: $\frac{5 \times 4\times 4 \times 6}{9\times 8\times 7}$? or in the other post, you suggested multiplying the numerator with $3\choose 1$ or $3 \choose 2$, all of which are not equal to $\frac{{5\choose 2}{4\choose 1}}{9\choose 3}$.

Answer (score 2):

$5/18$ is the probability for obtaining a red ball and then a black ball, when drawing two balls one by one.

$5/18$ is also the probability for obtaining a black ball and then a red ball.

The sum is $5/9$, which is the probability for obtain a red and a black ball in either order.

> Somehow using combinatorial formula captures the whole thing in a single step that I don't need to worry about each case separately, although on the numerator we considered the red ball first, then the black ball.

No it is not; The order of the binomial coefficients in the numerator does not reflect any consideration of order of drawing.  Both the numerator and denominator count ways to make selections without regard to arrangement of those selected items.

The count for obtaining one from five and one from four when selecting any two from all nine is thus : $$\dfrac{\dbinom 51\dbinom 41}{\dbinom 92}~=~\dfrac{\dfrac{5!}{1!~4!}\dfrac{4!}{1!~3!}}{\dfrac{9!}{2!~7!}}~=~\dfrac{5\cdot 4\cdot 2\color{silver}{\,\cdot 1}}{9\cdot 8}$$

Comment: " The order of the binomial coefficients in the numerator does not reflect any consideration of the order of drawing." Can you please explain this in detail? why don't we do $\frac{{5 \choose 1}\times{4 \choose 1}}{9 \choose 2} + \frac{{4 \choose 1}\times{5 \choose 1}}{9 \choose 2}$?? why is it invalid?